# http.client.InvalidURL issue

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to use an API, when I try to connect to this API it displays the error:

```
  File "C:\python_course\server.py", line 16, in <module>
  conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https://libredte.cl")
  File "C:\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1367, in __init__
  super(HTTPSConnection, self).__init__(host, port, timeout,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 829, in __init__
  (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 872, in _get_hostport
  raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
  http.client.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//libredte.cl'
```

My code is this one:

```
import socket
import http.client
import mimetypes
import json
import base64
import sys

mi_socket = socket.socket()
mi_socket.bind( ('localhost', 5404) )
mi_socket.listen(5)

cmd = 'user:password'

b64cmd = base64.b64encode(cmd.encode('utf_16_le')).decode('utf-8')

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https://libredte.cl")
```

What could the problem be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the protocol part from the url :

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("libredte.cl")
```